# how to populate a Listview with firebase data using Nativescript and Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, listview, nativescript

what is the simplest way to display a listview with firebase data?

for example I'll be retrieving data from firebase by query, how do I set that data into an Array item and let it display in a listview?

I've tried googling this but there seems to be no tutorial/ examples for it

Sample codes would be much appreciated! Thanks!

firebase query:

```
getValue: function () {
        var onQueryEvent = function(result) {

          console.log("Query result: " + JSON.stringify(result));


          };
        firebase.query(
          onQueryEvent,
          "/advisory_post",
          {
            singleEntry: true,
            orderBy: {
              type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.KEY
            }
          }
          );

      };
```

result:
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iugS.png)

Comment: You said you are using a query to retrieve the data. Share what the output of that query looks like and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've updated my question please take a look